# Don't send outgoing mail via Spamassassin

Tags: postfix, smtp, spamassassin, debian-jessie

My e-mail server is running Postfix 2.11.3 on Debian 8.7 (Jessie) with Spamassassin 3.4.0.

I realized that my outgoing e-mails are also being checked for spam, which not only seems to be unnecessary to me, it also adds headers to the e-mail which I would prefer to not be added.

Whenever I send an e-mail I see a line in my logfile that looks something like this:

```
postfix/pipe [...] to=<...>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.73, delays=0.22/0/0/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
```

In my `main.cf` there is no word about Spamassassin and in my `master.cf` I explicitly only include it as an option in the `smtp` service:

```
smtp          inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

The submission service doesn't have that option.

Why is Postfix delivering the e-mail via the Spamassassin service instead of directly connecting to the recipient?